# Unfathomable error using F# sequences

Tags: .net, f#, seq

I had some reliably working code using lists like:

```
      let rec srch (tzs : pqCell list) =
            match tzs with
            | h :: t ->
                 // process h and recurse on t if needed
            | [] -> None

      let zs = this.CellsInDiffOrder()   // a newly constructed list 
               |> List.filter (fun c -> c.nVal = 0 )
      srch zs
```

I then converted it to using sequences instead, as in many cases it was unnecessarily constructing large lists when the recursion terminated early on.

```
      let rec srch (tzs : pqCell seq) =
            if (Seq.isEmpty tzs) then None
            else
                let h = Seq.head tzs
                let t = Seq.skip 1 tzs
                // process h and recurse on t if needed

      let zs = this.CellsInDiffOrder()   // a newly constructed seq 
               |> Seq.filter (fun c -> c.nVal = 0 )
      srch zs
```

This appeared to work brilliantly, yielding dramatic performance improvements.  However, for reasons I am unable to fathom, this sometimes (but not always) fails with the message:

```
The input sequence has an insufficient number of elements.
```

and the following stack trace:

at Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.SeqModule.Skip@1500.GenerateNext(IEnumerable`1& next)
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Core.CompilerServices.GeneratedSequenceBase`1.MoveNextImpl()
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.SeqModule.Skip@1500.GenerateNext(IEnumerable`1& next)
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Core.CompilerServices.GeneratedSequenceBase`1.MoveNextImpl()
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.SeqModule.Skip@1500.GenerateNext(IEnumerable`1& next)
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Core.CompilerServices.GeneratedSequenceBase`1.MoveNextImpl()
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.SeqModule.Skip@1500.GenerateNext(IEnumerable`1& next)
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Core.CompilerServices.GeneratedSequenceBase`1.MoveNextImpl()
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.SeqModule.Skip@1500.GenerateNext(IEnumerable`1& next)
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Core.CompilerServices.GeneratedSequenceBase`1.MoveNextImpl()
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.SeqModule.Skip@1500.GenerateNext(IEnumerable`1& next)
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Core.CompilerServices.GeneratedSequenceBase`1.MoveNextImpl()
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.SeqModule.IsEmpty[T](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at PsQ2.srch@2506-2.Invoke(IEnumerable`1 zs) in C:\dev\psq\psq2.fs:line 2506
   at PsQ2.Search() in C:\dev\psq\psq2.fs:line 2530

So the skip 1 appears to fail, but why, as the code only ever skips on a sequence known to be not empty.  I am certain that no other code gets to see or modify any of the seqs in question, so what gives?

Comment: Can you reproduce the input that leads to the problem?

Comment: It's not entirely clear what your code does or what's the minimal program that compiles and reproduces your issue.

Comment: This sort of processing will be incredibly slow if you have to recurse deeply into the list

Comment: Ganesh:  Yes, the problem is reproducible - the same input causes it to fail at the same point.

Comment: GregC: I was hoping someone might be able to explain why such a refactoring was unsound.  Constructing the minimal program to reproduce the issue is likely to take some time.

Comment: John:  Yes, there is a definite trade-off here.  I was just trying some experimental refactorings to see if I could speed things up.  The example I gave appeared to give enormous gains, except for the fact that it errors under some circumstance.  The stacktrace I provided was complete, so it clearly wasn't due to deep recursion.

Comment: The most likely explanation to me (as an outsider to your code) is that whatever backs the `seq` inside `CellsInDiffOrder` can change while the sequence is being evaluated. With a list the whole thing is enumerated up front so that couldn't come up. But you'll need to provide a small reproducible example for this question to be properly answerable by others.

Comment: not sure how big the sequence is, but can you recreate on here with some more code: http://www.tryfsharp.org/Create

Comment: The stack trace shows that the a call to `Seq.isEmpty` is stepping through your sequence, which consists of several skip calls and eventually one of them hits an empty sequence. The code you have shown does not look like it could generate a sequence with a failing skip, so that suggests that the problem is in the code that you have not shown, either the recursion into `srch` or the initial seq generation in `CellsInDiffOrder`. Is there another call to `Seq.skip` in that code?
Note, the stack trace is a good example of why this could be very slow, all that just to check if sequence is empty.

Comment: @stephensong I would like to help you with your question, but only if it demonstrates that you've done all you could to research it and prepare it for general audience familiar with subject matter (F# in this case).

Comment: Many thanks to all for your helpful comments. Alas I have been unable to reproduce the error in a minimal program.  Given the expressed concerns about performance anyway I have moved on to a different approach altogether.  My apologies for wasting your collective time. I've still no clue as to how the error arose, but the mystery will have to remain unsolved.

Answer (score 3):

Since I do not know your code, let me show you a simple sequence that passes not isEmpty and fails on get head.

```
let i = ref 1
let s = seq { while !i <> 0 do i := 0; yield !i }
//let s = Seq.cache s  //add this line to make things works

assert not (Seq.isEmpty s) //isEmpty works by trying to take one element
let h = Seq.head s
```

Comment: interesting, but what if one does not want a cached sequence due to memory limitations? in my opinion, Seq.isEmpty should not change the value of it's argument. this is a very annoying side-effect